# Troubles installing JDK on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, java

I followed this instruction 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7
to install Java on my Ubuntu system, but to the line

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java" 1
```

I just get this response:

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode.
```

Can someone tell me how to install it?

Comment: Why didn't you post this at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)?

Comment: That looks like an informational message, not an error message. What happens after you get that message?

Comment: nothing happens. that's the only output

Comment: You may also want to try asking on [our Unix and Linux sister site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Run this command in the terminal : `java -version` if you get a version, java is installed...

Comment: Something *has* to happen, whether or not you get any other output. Does your computer freeze? Does the command-line return to the prompt? What happens next?

Comment: it returns to the prompt

Comment: and: sleonhardt@sleonhardt-VirtualBox:/usr/bin$ java -version
-bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it worked? What's the output of `java -version`? If it says "Java version 1.7.0" you're all set.

Comment: sleonhardt@sleonhardt-VirtualBox:/usr/bin$ java -version -bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Hmmm, that looks pretty bad. Have you tried removing all java related packages and reinstalling altogether? The command for removing packages is `aptitude purge`

Comment: does that only remove java related stuff or how do I specify that?

Comment: Check your java related packages with `dpkg -l | grep -i java`, then delete those with `aptitude purge`.

Comment: there aren't any; ii  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 ii  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 ii  libjs-jquery

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the installation link you provided. Please try installing the java7 package from the repository as outlined here: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-ubuntu-12-04.html